# What's the name of this sci-fi novel about Mars?

Tags: story-identification, novel, mars

The initial main protagonist, who has an Indian-sounding name, thinks he is man but discovers later on that he is a cyborg.  (Indian meaning from the country in Asia rather than from the Americas.)

Other characters take the lead including an old refugee woman who is reborn when they enter an abandoned city.  The cities are automated and move themselves around, gangs of scavengers try to capture and exploit parts of the cities.

Read about 10 yrs ago, medium thick paperback, darkish cover of stars and planets.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You may want to take the [tour], to better understand how our site works. You've got a great start here, and it may be enough for someone to answer your question. However, you may want to take a look at the answers to [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/); it may prompt you to things of additional hints you can edit into the question, to provide more info to help us help you! Some examples - when did you read the book? Any idea how old it was then? Do you remember anything about the cover?

Comment: By an "Indian sounding name" do you mean from the country India or do you mean a native American type name like Sitting Bull?

Comment: Hi thanks, I mean India as in the country, not north american native. So a name like Salman or Saloman

Comment: It was rad about 10 yrs ago, medium thick paperback, darkish cover of stars and planets.

Comment: Was the woman that is reborn a red head? If so, I think this is a Larry Niven story.

Comment: @zeta-band I think you are confusing this story with Niven's _A World out of Time,_ which took place on a climate-changed Earth (not Mars), and the protagonist (Corbell) was not a cyborg.

Comment: @MikeHarris You are correct, that is the story I was thinking of.

Comment: Based on the mention of moving cities on mars this could possibly be The Quantum Thief by Hannu Rajaniemi although not much else about it seems to match... here is the wikipedia page if it helps. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Quantum_Thief the  mention of  scavengers attacking the cities also reminds me of Strength of Stones by Greg Bear but again there is a lot that doesn't match.

Comment: "The cities are automated and move themselves around, gangs of scavengers try to capture and exploit parts of the cities." Makes me think of "Great Sky River" by Gregory Benford.